# Dropdown menu using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown in my menu for a site I'm creating with bootstrap and the dropdown doesn't seem to work. I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 Below is the code for my dropdown:

```html
<li class="dropdown">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Art</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="UploadArt.aspx">Upload Art</a></li>
  <li><a href="SearchForArt.aspx">Search For Art</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

And after doing a little bit of research, I've read that the order of the .js, .css, and jQuery links might have an affect. This is the current order I have them in, perhaps this order is what is causing the problem:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="Styles/css/NewStrap.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
 <script src="Styles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesnt work` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what was wrong. Bootstrap 2.3.2 is not compatible with JQuery 3.0 and higher. Using JQuery 1.9 fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

1st, load css first, put your css in `<head></head>` tag

2nd, load js before the `</body>`

example:

```html
<!-- load all css first -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Art</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="UploadArt.aspx">Upload Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="SearchForArt.aspx">Search For Art</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>


<!-- put all js before </body> tag -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It didn't work, the dropdown is still not showing. Currently I have it in the order: css, jquery, boostrap js, all in the head tag.

Comment: Oh I found out what was wrong. Boostrap 2.3.2 was not compatible with the new version of jquery I was using. Using Jquery 1.9 fixed it.